# Does Gmail use IMAP for itself?

Tags: email, email-client, gmail-imap, gmail-pop

I want to know that Gmail (Web client) uses IMAP for itself to show messages in Inbox and other folders and for other CRUD and other operations as any other Web mail client does like RoundCube or AtMail or it has its own internal methods to fetch emails and perform different operations?

**Please let me know... how Gmail works internally?**

Answer (score 1):

Gmail is not using IMAP for its native interface. It uses a closed source internal system.